# SQL Server : join tables result doesn't contain null values (I want it to)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables...

**Person:**

```
PersonID   FirstName   LastName
-------------------------------
   2       Jim         Smith
   4       David       Dill
   5       Sarah       Hill
   6       Eric        Ericson
```

**Pledge:**

```
PersonID   Amount   Year
------------------------
   4        1000    2017
   5        1000    2017
   6        1000    2017
```

**Contributions:**

```
PersonID  TotalToPresent  Year
------------------------------
   4          200         2017
   5          400         2017
```

I want to join the tables, with those who've pledged to be listed, despite having not given.

**Result:**

```
PersonID    Pledge    TotalToPresent  Year
------------------------------------------
   4         1000          200        2017
   5         1000          400        2017
   6         1000      NULL (or zero) 2017
```

However, my resultant table never includes anyone who has not given (is not present in contribution table)

My query:

```
SELECT 
    Person.PersonID,
    PLEDGES.PledgeAmount,
    PLEDGES.ContributionYear,
    Person.LastName,
    Person.FirstName,
    Person.PrimaryAssociationID,
    Contributions.TotalContrib
FROM 
    PLEDGES
INNER JOIN 
    (Contributions 
LEFT JOIN 
    Person ON Contributions.PersonID = Person.PersonID) 
    ON PLEDGES.PersonID = Person.PersonID 
FROM 
    PLEDGES 
INNER JOIN 
    Person ON PLEDGES.PersonID = Person.PersonID 
INNER JOIN 
    Contributions ON Person.PersonID = Contributions.PersonID 
WHERE  
    PLEDGES.Year = '2017' 
ORDER BY 
    Person.PersonID
```

Comment: INNER JOIN executed after OUTER JOIN removes NULL values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `INNER JOIN` the `Person` table to `PLEDGES`, to filter off anyone who has not even pledged.  Then do a `LEFT JOIN` to `Contributions` to possibly include information about contributions which a person made, beyond just having pledged.

```
SELECT t1.PersonID,
       t2.PledgeAmount,
       t2.ContributionYear,
       t1.LastName,
       t1.FirstName,
       t1.PrimaryAssociationID,
       COALESCE(t3.TotalContrib, 0.0) AS TotalContrib
FROM Person
INNER JOIN PLEDGES t2
    ON t1.PersonID = t2.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Contributions t3
    ON t1.PersonID = t3.PersonID
```

Note that you might also want to join `PLEDGES` to `Contributions` using the year, if your data could have more than one year.  I assumed in my answer that a given person has at most one entry in `PLEDGES` and `Contributions`.

Comment: This resulted in the needed data.  Thank you for explaining the solution in detail.  If I post again, I'll definitely beautify my SQL and tables....

Answer (score 0):

First off, put your sql through a formatter / beautifier.  It'll make your life lots easier.

Now for your question:  an inner join means that it'll only show matches.  What you're looking for is a left join.  So do something like this:

```
select
    *
from 
    table1 t1
    left join table2 t2
        t1.key = t2.foreign_key
    left join table3 t3
        t2.key = t3.foreign_key
order by
    whatever
```

Comment: `with those who've pledged to be listed` ... this implies he doesn't want to `LEFT JOIN` the person table, or, if you do, then you would need to add a `WHERE` condition to remove non-pledging persons.